# MySQL How to Select smth by MAX(id)....WHERE userID = some number GROUP BY smth

Tags: mysql

I have next table in my DB:

personal_prizes

```
 ___________ ___________ _________ __________
|    id     |    userId |   specId|   grp    |  
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
|    1      |    1      |   1     |     1    |  
|    2      |    1      |   2     |     1    |  
|    3      |    2      |   3     |     1    |  
|     4     |    2      |   4     |     2    |  
|     5     |    1      |   5     |     2    |  
|     6     |    1      |   6     |     2    |  
|    7      |    2      |   7     |     3    |  
|     8     |    1      |   13    |     4    |
|___________|___________|_________|__________|
```

I need to select specId by max id group by grp. 
So I have composed next query

```
SELECT pp.specId 
FROM personal_prizes pp
WHERE pp.specId IN (SELECT MAX(pp1.id) 
                    FROM personal_prizes pp1
                    WHERE pp1.userId = 1 
                    GROUP BY pp1.grp)
```

And it's work for my little table. But when I try to implement it for my prod db with personal_prizes > 100,000.
Please help me optimize it

Comment: We could try rewriting your query, but with only 100K records is performance really a problem for you?

Comment: Oh...Are there some another problems?

Comment: There is no problem.

Comment: But when I try to test in prod DB, where person_prizes.id's entries more than 100,000 it freezes. I tly it in phpmyadmin and get popup 'Loading'

Answer (score 0):

The query you have should work fine. Make sure though that you not only have an index on `id` (which I suppose is the primary key), but also one on `specId`.

Just as an alternative, you might try this one:

```
select    group_concat(pp.specId order by pp1.id desc)+0 as result_specId
from      personal_prizes pp1
left join personal_prizes pp on pp.specId = pp1.id
where     pp1.userId = 1 
group by  pp1.grp
having    result_specId is not null;
```

The idea here is that the sub query is promoted to the main query, and the `specId` is retrieved by an outer join. The `group_concat` aggregation function will list the one of interest as the first. The `having` clause will exclude the cases where no matching `specId` was found.

Note that this will only give the same results if the `specId` field is guaranteed to be non-null.

Comment: Oh, your alternative query works! Thanks! But it takes 6,5 seconds((( Can you help me to reduce this time with another query?

Comment: You can get better execution time if you have an index on `specId`. Do you have that?

Comment: In your sample data `specId` is always equal to `id`. I suppose there cases where they are different?

Comment: Yes, such cases exists. I've already changed sample data in question

Comment: Do you have an index on `userId, grp, id`? What does `explain select ... ` give as output?